# Hibernate one-to-many mapping (annotations)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, annotations, one-to-many

I am new to hibernate, I am trying to learn it and I have run into a problem trying to make one to many relationship's work. I have tried several examples but none seem to be working.

Can someone have a look at the below code and tell me where I have gone wrong. I have tried many different tutorials but it always doesn't work, so I must be missing something.

There are two classes: MovieDb and Genre. For each movie there should be many Genre's.

I believe I have included all the files and information needed, if not let me know.

Thanks for the help.

**MovieDb.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
public class MovieDb extends IdElement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    @Column(name = "movieId")
    private int movieId;

    @JsonProperty("title")
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("genres")
    @OneToMany
    private List<Genre> genres;

    public int getMovieId() { return movieId; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public List<Genre> getGenres() { return genres; }

    public void setMovieId(int movieId) { this.movieId = movieId; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
    public void setGenres(List<Genre> genres) { this.genres = genres; }
}
```

**Genre.java**

```
@JsonRootName("genre")
@Entity
@Table(name = "moviesGenre")
public class Genre implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "movieId")
    private int movieId;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public int getMovieId() { return movieId; }
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setMovieId(int movieId) { this.movieId = movieId; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public MovieDb getMovie(int movieId) {
    Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
    MovieDb movie = null;
    try {
        String hql = "FROM MovieDb E WHERE E.movieId = " + movieId;
        Query query = s.createQuery(hql);
        List movies = query.list();
        movie = (MovieDb)movies.get(0); 
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException ex) {
        if (tx != null) 
            tx.rollback();
    }finally {
        s.close(); 
    }
    return movie;
}

public void saveMovie(MovieDb movie) {
    Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
    try {
        s.save(movie);
        s.flush();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        if (tx != null) 
            tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        s.close(); 
    }
}
```

My database is setup like this:

**movies**

```
id          int           (primary)
movieId     int
title       varchar
```

**moviesGenre**

```
id          int           (primary)
movieId     int 
name        varchar
```

My Hibernate.cfg.xml file showing mapping is below:

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <mapping class="com.medialibrary.api.model.MovieDb"/>
    <mapping class="com.medialibrary.api.model.Genre"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the MovieDb class side

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Genre> genres;
```

and in Genre

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="movieId")
    private MovieDb movie;
```

Bugs in the code:

when you are saving parent entity then them children are not persisted as long as you do not use CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL (for all the operation types)

you are trying to do a bidirectional relation so you have to specify the owner
mappedBy="movie" will do this job - it says that a moveId will be written on the Genre side

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I use your code above I get the following error: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.medialibrary.api.model.Genre column: movieId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: have you removed this field @Column(name = "movieId") private int movieId; ?  If not just do this and only to be sure remove its setters/getters as well.

Comment: It works if I remove the above code although on the db, moviesGenre -> movieId is null.

Comment: you will get that effect when you not set a parent object to children. Remember now Genre has a reference to its parent and this has to be set as well So .. genre.setMovie(movie); In other words movie has to have genre in its collection and genre has to have movie field set.

Comment: The best way and I think a common way to do that is to create another method in MovieDb addGenre(Genre genre){this.genres.add(genre); genre.setMovie(this)}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not sure how to implement your code into my code though, could you show me an example?

Comment: try tutorials nr 14 and 15:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mANZ4MMbD4&list=PL4AFF701184976B25
Basically I will recommend to you the whole series. They are very useful and brain friendly.